# Cocoa Touch Framework with dependency - how to compile but not link?

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I"m creating a dynamic framework (Cocoa Touch Framework) which uses the Facebook SDK frameworks. My framework will be distributed without source code, and will be added to our client's iOS apps. Since the Facebook SDK works as a singleton, it must be added to the client app, not my framework. But how can I compile my framework without including it? From what I've read, I should be able to build with just the Facebook framework headers. I've tried every method out there, but I always get linker errors (undefined symbols).